# Interpreting sentiment analysis (NRC lexicon)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, interpretation

I'm trying to apply [NRC dictionary](http://saifmohammad.com/WebPages/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon.htm) to a particular text for sentiment analysis. It can be found in 'syuzhet' package.

Unfortunately, unlike on this [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/syuzhet/vignettes/syuzhet-vignette.html), I am not getting result data frame with each row representing a sentence from file (get_nrc_sentiment part).

Does this have something to do with text organization? I kept all the punctuation in text, still it returns me just one row with some numbers for each emotion, which I don't know how to interpret.

Answer (score -1):

get_nrc_sentiment function, for each of the words in the given sentence/data frame, returns a data frame with values for each emotions and sentiments, based on the match with the list of words and it emotions.

For example:
get_nrc_sentiment("I love icecreams")

anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive

1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0        1

Here the word love had made the counter for "joy" and "positive" to be incremented by one. Similarly all the other words, if found a match or carries a emotion/sentiment, will be represented by this data frame.

Hope this helps.